# Can I ask about multiple problems with my WP in one thread?

Tags: discussion

I'm having a few problems with my Nokia Lumia 1520, should I break it up in different threads or can I put all of them in one thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd they are unrelated you must post separately.

But if they are the same main subject you can ask in the same thread.

Like "can't sync my Gmail and my Outlook account" just needs one thread.

Make sure there isn't a question about the same problem.